# Using secrets with azure/docker-login

Tags: azure, docker, github-actions

I have a GitHub Action that uses `azure/docker-login@v1` for building and pushing images to the Azure image registry, and it works.

Now, I want to pass GITHUB_TOKEN using Docker's **secret** flag, but it only accepts a file, and I don't know how to create a file using this action.

Is it possible?

For example, with `docker/build-push-action` I can do this bellow

```
  - name: Build docker image
    uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
    with:
      context: .
      secrets: |
        "github_token=${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
```

How can I secure my image using `azure/docker-login`?

Comment: Could you please link to the section from here (https://github.com/Azure/docker-login/tree/v1) that you're trying to use and add the respective portion to your question as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [readme.md](https://github.com/Azure/docker-login) of the `azure/docker-login` action suggests:

> Use this GitHub Action to log in to a private container registry such as Azure Container registry. Once login is done, the next set of actions in the workflow can perform tasks such as building, tagging and pushing containers.

You can setup your workflow so that it logs in using `azure/docker-login` and builds and pushes the image using `docker/build-push-action`, like this:

```
- uses: azure/docker-login@v1
  with:
    login-server: contoso.azurecr.io
    username: ${{ secrets.ACR_USERNAME }}
    password: ${{ secrets.ACR_PASSWORD }}
  
- uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
  with:
    push: true
    context: .
    secrets: |
    "github_token=${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
```